# How to check programmatically if an IAM user signing in AWS console without MFA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to use an AWS service or a combination of services to check if the signed-in IAM user used MFA or not.

I tried with cloud watch Events and Lambda. By using this, I could check the details of the user sign in the event object. But, I cannot able to check whether he signed in using MFA or not.

Any Suggestions?

UPDATE:
I used, CloudWatch Event rules -> Source: Build Event by Service (Service Name:AWS Console Sign-in, Event Type: Sign-in) -> Target: Lambda/SNS email. Then I got he below information:
sample Event object which I got:

```
{
   "version":"0",
   "id":"XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX",
   "detail-type":"AWS Console Sign In via CloudTrail",
   "source":"aws.signin",
   "account":"XXXXXXXXX",
   "time":"2020-12-14T12:03:43Z",
   "region":"us-east-2",
   "resources":[
      
   ],
   "detail":{
      "eventVersion":"1.05",
      "userIdentity":{
         "type":"IAMUser",
         "principalId":"XXXXXXXX",
         "arn":"arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:user/XXXXX",
         "accountId":"XXXXX",
         "userName":"XXXX"
      },
      "eventTime":"2020-12-14T12:03:43Z",
      "eventSource":"signin.amazonaws.com",
      "eventName":"ConsoleLogin",
      "awsRegion":"us-east-2",
      "sourceIPAddress":"XX.XX.XX.XX",
      "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ",
      "requestParameters":null,
      "responseElements":{
         "ConsoleLogin":"Success"
      },
      "additionalEventData":{
         "LoginTo":"https://XXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      },
      "eventID":"XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX",
      "eventType":"AwsConsoleSignIn"
   }
}
```

Comment: " I cannot able to check whether he signed in using MFA or not." - why cannot? The info about MFA should be there.

Comment: @Marcin I just updated the Event object I am getting (See the Update). Seems like I don't get MFA details. But I signed in as MFA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example event indicates that the user did not login with MFA. If they had, the `additionalEventData` would include an `MFAUsed` value, like this:

```
    "additionalEventData": {
        "LoginTo": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/console/home?region=us-east-1&state=hashArgs%23&isauthcode=true",
        "MobileVersion": "No",
        "MFAUsed": "Yes"
    },
```

I suspect, however, that this data is less useful than you might think. For example, if you use SAML-based authentication, or even (I believe) AWS Single SignOn, you won't see this information. The reason is that such authentication methods -- even if they support MFA -- do not convey that information to AWS.

It can be even more complicated if you use assumed roles, where the indication of AWS MFA is in the `userIdentity` object.

If you're looking for users that don't have MFA enabled, the best solution imo is to go to the Console's user list.

Comment: Firstly, I Signed in with MFA and I got this event. Secondly, I do not use SSO/SAML based auth. I signed in with AWS providing the account number, username, and password.

Comment: I just updated my question to give more information.

Comment: I would look at the original event, to see if it has the `MFAUsed` element. It is possible that not all of the event components are provided to EventBridge (aka CloudWatch Events). If that turns out to be the case, you'll need to follow the advice of the other answer, and retrieve the original event in your Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AWS CloudTrail combined with LookupEvents API using SDK of your choice (Python, JS, Java etc).

First one will capture any IAM calls, even multi-regionally if required, and second will query the results of the capture. You should be able to see the required MFA info in the event body.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cloudtrail-integration.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/APIReference/API_LookupEvents.html